# what is actual and formal argument lists differ in length and how to fix it in my code

Tags: java, list

so i keep getting this error when i try to run my program the problem is i dont know what is in the driver. thats part of the assignment. this is the line of code i believe is giving me the issue.

```
public VotingMachine(int d, int r, int i) {
    dVotes = d;
    rVotes = r;
    iVotes = i;
}
```

and this is the error i keep getting.

```
/tmp/codecheck/17091202408150120863985811601/submission/VotingSimulation.java:9
error: constructor VotingMachine in class VotingMachine cannot be applied to given types;

VotingMachine vm = new VotingMachine();
                   ^
required: int,int,int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I have no idea why its doing this please help if you need more info let me know or other lines of code.

Comment: It is expecting 3 parameters, and you're passing none. What do you expect values of `d`, `r`, and `i` to be? You have to supply 3 values to call that constructor.

Comment: you see im supposed to be taking in 3 args from the driver im not given the values of d, r ,i. i thought that in the driver those values are declared but like i said earlier i cant see the driver that was provided so idk what too do

Comment: If by *"i cant see the driver"* you mean that you can't see the code with the `new VotingMachine()` call, then you have to change your constructor to not require any arguments. Or you could add an overload, if you also need one that does take arguments, e.g. `public VotingMachine() { this(0, 0, 0); }`

Answer (score 0):

In java, if you provide a constructor with arguments, you must explicitly provide no-arg constructor; it will not be there implicitly.

I.e. Add a no-arg constructor to class

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear, your constructor accepts three integers as :

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
VotingMachine vm = new VotingMachine(a, b , c);
```